# How to solve a congruence of a polynomial $x^3+2x^2+x+2\equiv 0 \mod 45$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, congruences

$x^3+2x^2+x+2\equiv 0 \mod 45$

$f(x)=(x^2+1)(x+2)$

by inspection

$\fbox{1}$$x=7$ is a possible solution $\mod 9$  ,since $45=5\times 3^2$

$\fbox{2} $ $x= 2 $ is  a solution $\mod 5$ but i want to get general work on how to find other solutions...from here >>>

Comment: Use Extended Chinese Remainder Theorem with primes 3 and 5.

Comment: $ x \equiv 2 (mod 5)$ and $ x \equiv 3 (mod 5)$ are solutions.

Comment: thank you,i understand now,so besides using CRT how can i use Hensel's theorem to do this problem

Comment: You can try it for the prime 3. Figure out the solutions modulo 3 and then try lifting it.

Answer (score 2):

First work with modulo 9:

$$f(x) = (x^2 + 1)(x + 2) \equiv 0 \pmod 9$$

Now we have three distinct cases, because 9 is square of 3:

**Case 1: $9\mid (x^2 + 1)$**

This case is impossible, because $-1$ isn't quadratic residue modulo $9$.

**Case 2: $3\mid (x^2 + 1)$ and $3\mid (x+2)$**

The first relation is impossible, because $-1$ isn't quadratic residue modulo $3$.

**Case 3: $9\mid (x+2)$**

This is the only case possible and is satisfied when $x \equiv 7 \pmod 9$

So this implies that $f(x) \equiv 0 \pmod 9$ if and if $x \equiv 7 \pmod 9$

Now work modulo 5:

$$f(x) = (x^2 + 1)(x + 2) \equiv 0 \pmod 5$$

Because $5$ is prime number we have only two cases:

**Case 1: $5\mid (x^2+1)$**

We know that $-1$ is quadratic residue modulo $5$ and it implies that $x \equiv \pm 2 \pmod 5$

**Case 1: $5\mid (x+2)$**

This one implies that $x \equiv -2 \pmod 5$

So from this we obtain that $f(x) \equiv 0 \pmod 5$ if and only if $x \equiv \pm 2 \pmod 5$

Now apply Chinese Remainder Theorem for two cases:

**Case 1: $x \equiv 2 \pmod 5$ and $x \equiv 7 \pmod 9$**

The first conguence relation is equivalent to $x \equiv 7 \pmod 5$, so using this and the second congruence relation $x \equiv 7 \pmod {45}$

**Case 2: $x \equiv -2 \pmod 5$ and $x \equiv 7 \pmod 9$**

Applying CRT we get that $x \equiv -2 \equiv 43 \pmod {45}$

So we have two solutions:

$$x \equiv 7,43 \pmod {45}$$

Answer (score 0):

If you want to solve it without explicitly stating the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Hint :$ x \equiv 7 \pmod 9$ so $ x = 9k+ 7 $ for some $k$.

Now, $ 9k + 7 \equiv ? \pmod 5$.

Solve for $k$.